# Adding HTML and JavaScript to a page with the Avada Theme in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I'm creating a page in Wordpress and need to add a custom Facebook share button. In order to do so, I need to add FB's JavaScript and HTML code in the header.

I don't even know where to put this since we have the Avada theme and all I can see is the Fusion page builder. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: In addition to the links Axel provided, please also review: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I didn't think a code example was necessary as the question was not about coding but how to access a section of a wordpress theme to add code. I spent a half-hour looking for an answer and was unable to do so, thus the reason for my post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below the Dashboard link, you should see a link that says Avada. Hover over that, and go to Theme Options. From there scroll down to Advanced. Then go to Code Fields. Put your code in the "Space before head" code box.